# Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 Error

Tags: sql, excel, import

After hours of searching and coming up empty, I've decided to seek additional help.

I'm running the following command

```
select  * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel
12.0;Database=C:\SAMPLE.xlsx;HDR=YES', 'SELECT * FROM [sheet1$]')
```

I receive the normal error that everyone else receives.

```
Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)"
reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.

Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider 
"Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)".
```

Currently I'm running Windows Server 2003 R2 64 Bit and using Windows Office 2007.  I am running under an administrative account, so I know it's not having to do with the TEMP permission issue that I've seen.

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1; 
RECONFIGURE; 
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1; 
RECONFIGURE; 
GO 

USE [master] 
GO 
EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'AllowInProcess', 1
GO 
EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'DynamicParameters', 1 
GO
```

Has been run.

At first I was getting the error and as I tried other commands it started to hang up on me and I fixed that by adding the -g512; in front of the Startup Parameter and that fixed the issue. But, now I'm back to the original error.

I have uninstalled and reinstalled the Access Drivers and that didn't help either.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is your sheet really called "Sheet"? I would have expected "Sheet1" or some number.

Comment: Adjusted, it is Sheet1.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
*
FROM
OPENDATASOURCE('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','Data source = "C:\SAMPLE.xlsx"; Extended proprietes="Excel 12.0";HDR=YES;IMEX=1;')...[sheet1$]
```